# how to get the max column value from msyql table using subquery when the values are decimal and non decimal

Tags: mysql, subquery, max, decimal, largenumber

```
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| id | user_email              | cat_id | sub_cat_id | score | out_of | score_in_per | date       | groupId | groupType |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 13 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 40    | 40     | 100          | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 14 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 37    | 40     | 92.5         | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 15 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 35    | 54     | 90.35        | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 17 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 75    | 41     | 91.52        | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 20 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 47    | 56     | 85           | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 35 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 14    | 89     | 20.45        | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 37 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 69    | 78     | 45.45        | 22-04-2017 | 34      | institute |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

from the above table i want to get max `score_in_per` value as a sub query but due to decimal it is not working by desc or `max(score_in_per)` so how can ni get the max `score_in_per`

> this is what i have tried but the max value is not coming..

```
(SELECT MAX(score_in_per) 
FROM tbl_student_skill_score WHERE cat_id=9 
and sub_cat_id=11
ORDER BY score_in_per DESC)  as maxPortaScore
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is with `ORDER BY score_in_per DESC`, not `MAX`.  What do you get for the MAX?  Or maybe the problem is with the outer query??  Please show that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
max(cast(score_in_per as decimal(5,2)))
FROM tbl_student_skill_score WHERE cat_id=9 
and sub_cat_id=11
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps you.

Comment: thankx it is working.. can you please explain what is cast and how decimal(5,2) is working..?

Comment: If this actually fixes your problem, then you must be storing your percentage scores as text (which you shouldn't be doing).  The cast brings it back to a number so that the query works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches here.  If you want to use the `MAX()` function, then you don't need `ORDER BY`.  Hence, the following should work:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(score_in_per AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS maxPortaScore
FROM tbl_student_skill_score
WHERE cat_id = 9 AND sub_cat_id = 11
```

The other approach would be to use `ORDER BY` on the score column, and then restrict the result set to only the first record, i.e. the maximum score:

```
SELECT CAST(score_in_per AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM tbl_student_skill_score
WHERE cat_id = 9 AND sub_cat_id = 11
ORDER BY CAST(score_in_per AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I updated the above going by the accepted answer which implies that `score_in_per` is being stored as text.

Comment: both the above queries are not working when there is `100` max record is there. it is still showing `92.5 record.`